Lightweight Linux distribution for Arduino programming, web search and Cura
I have several older Laptops (~10 years old) which currently run Windows 10. We run them in a makerspace-like environment. With the end of support of Windows 10, I am now looking for a Linux distribution with the following requirements:

is lightweight, i.e. boots fast and is responsive
works well with little RAM (some 4 GB, most 8 GB)
works with smaller hard drives (240 GB, including all apps mentioned below)
has a similar look and feel like Windows 10, because that's what we are used to
has excellent hardware support, so I don't need to fiddle around on the command line for days. Our hardware are Dell and Lenovo Laptops.
is gratis

The following applications must be supported:

a browser, e.g. Firefox for web research
video codecs, so we can watch Youtube tutorials and similar
Arduino IDE 2.x (so the Linux has to be 64 bit) for programming
Cura, so we can prepare stuff for 3D printing
a PDF reader (we used Foxit Reader)
a markdown editor, e.g. Obsidian
an Office Suite to write "Word" documents, e.g. LibreOffice. We use LibreOffice already.
we currently use local user profiles on Windows, since we don't have a server. We plan to have remote user profiles and a server, so that anyone can log on at any Laptop have get his data back.

I have not used GUI Linux for more than 10 years now. However, I still have a headless Debian server.
Please do not suggest:

Ubuntu. I used Ubuntu from 2004 to 2011, until they suddenly switched to Unity, which f***ed up everything for me. I switched back to Windows due to that incident. I'm still done with Ubuntu.
something where I compile my own kernel. I will not.

I have tried:

Elementary OS but it hangs during boot with Lenovo laptops
Fedora but that one is too far from Windows. I only need one Desktop and the shutdown button bottom left. Also, it doesn't show any messages during boot, so I was tempted to power the laptop off. There must be some progress, at least. Staring at a black screen is not what users do.

